# How to tell whether mysql was built with libedit or readline?

Tags: mysql, command-line

How to tell whether mysql was built with libedit or readline?

I'm trying to configure the mysql client tool to use Ctrl-R for searching command history but not sure which input library my installation is using.

Comment: Possibly relevent: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If on Linux you can just use `ldd` to check which libraries it's dynamically linked against:

```
phil@ironforge:~$  ldd `which mysql`
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd5add5000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007eff0a44e000)
        libreadline.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.5 (0x00007eff0a210000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007eff09fee000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007eff09dc4000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007eff09baa000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007eff099a6000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007eff09623000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007eff0931a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007eff08f50000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055960d9f2000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007eff08d39000)
phil@ironforge:~$
```

In this example on my host, it's linked against `libreadline`.

It's also in the `--help` output:

```
phil@ironforge:~$ mysql --help | grep readline
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
phil@ironforge:~$
```

Comment: This works, though I had to use `otool -L $(which mysql)` instead of ldd because my macos didn't have ldd (or I haven't found it yet).